# Why doesn't typescript complain when I ignore generic type definitions?

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

Imagine you have the following code:

```js
class Superclass<T>{
    combine(object: Superclass<T>) {
        console.log("combined!");
        return object;
    }
}

class Generic1 {
    x = 12;
    // some class...
}
class Generic2 {
    y = "Hello!";
    // some class...
}

new Superclass<Generic1>().combine(new Superclass<Generic2>());
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKCuAHApgJ1JCAeAKgPgG8AoaU6YAewFsAjASwDtkAKCmgK2WABcAuOJGgxRceAJTRiZaeQoMIFEMgB0ICgHNmAIkq1GyACYBCLWIDcJGaVTJu8VA2htOPC9IC+RT0WEwA4shMqHTAAIySlqQAHtAAvNChAExuZAD0qdAKVMjk4FDKBV4+ef6BaCGJEdIAnnHQWgASyCBqJimk6ZnUOb4FykVETADuAijoJVgBQSGheMxiyrr0TMzDo0ITU+XAiXNi5kA)

As you will surely notice, there should be an error here. `Superclass<Generic1>` can only be combined with `Superclass<Generic1>`, but in no case with `Superclass<Generic2>`. Visual studio code also displays this:

[image]

But there is no error after compiling! Why? Am I misunderstanding generics?

Comment: I have now found out that an error only occurs [when I use the generic type T in an attribute of the class Superclass<T>](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKCuAHApgJ1JCAeAKgPgG8AoaU6AFwAsBLAOwHMAuaHAbiJLOAHtaJzU8YOW6oAFFTpMWASmjEyiijQgA6SQ2gBeZVPaKAvh0U8AtgCM6yMd3MArZMOYIU6cFFx45CpaR59uEGRVEG56MQAiM0taZAATAEIImX1faFRkcnhUWmhbB2FU0iMjIgwoaABxZFjUamAARnlOUgAPbWgGgCYi6AB6PugIblNkaHK1VVUiIwmqmrR6rubFAE8OiIAJZBBQpN6BoZGxianp0tiAdzgkNAmsatr6hrwxK-mnxrEZGVVoqzeyGuLju7mwj0WwC6r3eELqUO+P1YQA).

Comment: That's a property, not an "attribute".

Comment: Ah, good, I was on the right track with the shape thing... :-D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TypeScript lets it go through because the `T` in `Superclass<T>` *does not affect its shape*, therefore `Superclass<A>` and `Superclass<B>` have the same shape, and are therefore considered "compatible" by TypeScript.

<sub>Remember that TypeScript has a *structural* type system where types are considered equivalent by their members, even if their actual and original definitions are completely separate (think of [convergent evolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergent_evolution)). As for why it's surprising: Remember that TypeScript does *not* have a nominative type-system, where types with identical members, structure and layout, right down to cross-platform binary representations, are considered strictly different, as long as they have different type-names (this is how Java, C#, and many other languages' type systems work).</sub>

So while `Superclass<T>` is not using `T` and it doesn't affect its shape, so `tsc` considers `T` superfluous and ignores it:

So this...

```
class Superclass<T> {
    combine(object: Superclass<T>): Superclass<T> { ... }
}
```

...is provably equivalent to:

```
class Superclass {
    combine(object: Superclass): Superclass { ... }
}
```

However, as soon as `Superclass<T>` becomes dependent upon `T`, such as by adding a field typed as `T`, then it throws an error:

```
class Superclass<T>{

    public value: T;

    constructor(value: T) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    combine(object: Superclass<T>) {
        console.log("combined: " + object.value.toString());
        return object;
    }
}

class Generic1 {
    x = Math.random();
}
class Generic2 {
    y = Math.random();
}

var x = new Superclass<Generic1>( new Generic1() ).combine(new Superclass<Generic2>( new Generic2() ) );
```

Error:

```
Argument of type 'Superclass<Generic2>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Superclass<Generic1>'.
  Property 'x' is missing in type 'Generic2' but required in type 'Generic1'.
```

---

As for *why this is the case* - this is (I think) explained in TypeScript's documentation [in the section about *Type Compatibility*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html):

> The basic rule for TypeScript’s structural type system is that `x` is compatible with `y` if `y` has at least the same members as `x`

In this case, when `Superclass<T>` is closed as either `Superclass<Generic1>` or as `Superclass<Generic2>` both types have exactly the same members, and TypeScript considers them compatible wither each other.

Comment: @MeineHTMLCodes I've updated my answer with an explanation after I read the docs.